# How can I have two versions of Xcode without conflicts?

Tags: xcode, beta

My stable version of Xcode, the previous one to Xcode 8, launched two days ago, use provisioning profiles for APNs and many other data. I'd like to install Xcode 8 to learn about the new features but I'm scared about damaging my current working Xcode version because the last time I installed a beta Xcode version I remember I couldn't send packages from the stable version, something like files from two versions overlapped becoming "main files" those from the beta version.

I need precise instructions about how to install a Xcode beta version in El Capitan having and older working version without damaging anything.

By the way... is it possible to install Xcode 8 in El Capitan? And submit compiled app from this version?

Comment: Typically, you can't submit store apps that are created with beta software.

Comment: and what about having two versions of Xcode without affecting each other the existence of other version? Can I having the two versions in the same application folder? with the same user's library folder?

Comment: I don't know.  I've done it in the past with some versions but I haven't attempted anything with 8 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Xcode-beta 8 from https://developer.apple.com as usual and you can Xcode 7 & 8 side by side as they have different names `Xcode-beta` and `Xcode` (see image)

[image]

Comment: and what about the Library/Developer folder? Don't they share the same folder?

Comment: Everything seems fine.  I've archived and uploaded a new Swift 3 project to iTunes Connect using Xcode 8 beta.

Comment: @RobLabs did you manage to submit it to the store? I keep getting the error LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS is 10.0. And I don't see any place to change that.

Comment: @Gerard, yes we submitted to iTunes Connect..  But we did not see that error.

Comment: @RobLabs I uploaded to connect too, but I mean submit to the store. I get the error when clicking "submit for review"

Comment: We have not submitted our app for TestFlight review, yet, as we have other items we are trying to place in that build.  So, you may be further along than we are.